# Django ForeignKey null=True fails to drop not null from column

Tags: django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, alter-table, notnull

## The problem:

Here's my class with two `ForeignKey`s (`dept` and `salary_range`). Note `null=True`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile')
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='/static/default.png')
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True)
    salary_range = models.ForeignKey(SalaryRange, null=True)
```

Running `python manage.py sqlall main` seems show the correct sql (no `NOT NULL` on `dept_id` and `salary_range_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE "main_userprofile" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "avatar" varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    "dept_id" integer REFERENCES "main_department" ("id"),
    "salary_range_id" integer REFERENCES "main_salaryrange" ("id"),
```

But an `IntegrityError` occurs when creating a `UserProfile`:

```
main_userprofile.dept_id may not be NULL
```

And upon inspection of the database, both columns are set `NOT NULL`. **How? Why?**

## The hack:

All I have been able to come up with is to alter the table after `syncdb`:

```
ALTER TABLE main_userprofile ALTER COLUMN dept_id DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE main_userprofile ALTER COLUMN salary_range_id DROP NOT NULL;
```

This works for Postgres, but sqlite does not have an `ALTER COLUMN` option..

## The Solution ??

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18109046/1628832)

Comment: You could also try explicitly specifying "blank=True" and "default=-1"

Comment: I understand `syncdb` will not alter the table. The issue exists from a fresh db.

Comment: Thanks, MikkoP :) I had tried using `default=0` before to no avail, but `defualt=-1` seems to be a useful work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything seems fine. As suggested in the comment, most likely when you ran `syncdb` the first time, at that time you did not had the options `null=True` for `dept` and `salary_range`. Then you changed your code however that did not modify the table definition. To solve that, you can either manually fix the issue by dropping the `NOT NULL` part or you can use database migrations apps. The most popular one is by far [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). South can detect changes in the model definitions and apply appropriate changes to your database (called database migrations) without loosing any data. South docs are pretty good so you should be able to start using it in no time.

PS - In future versions of Django (most likely Django 1.7), the migrations capability will be integrated directly into Django core however until then, South will have to do.

Comment: Ah, I just realized my error, and your review of South made the connection. I am already using South for this project. My error is that I had my production migrations still sitting around.  When I did a fresh remake of the db I was still loading the old versions of the migrations!